# Failed to update rows in "jinzhu/gorm" pkg

Tags: go, go-gorm

I need to update value of fields in multiple rows.

I'm querying to get some of the database rows, but it doesn't work.

```golang
DB.Where("is_send = ?", "0").Find(&artists)

for _, artist := range artists {
    if condition {
    artist.IsSend = 1
    ... (more updatee)
    DB.Save(&artist)
    }
}
```

Comment: use index like `artists[i].IsSend ` when update

Comment: @AbinashGhosh it's not work

Comment: what is type of  `artists` ? and check is data is loaded in `artists`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change how you range it, by referring the below example:

```golang
for _, elem := range elems {
    elem = new_val      // Won't work, because elem is a copy of 
                        // the value from elems
}

for i := range elems {
    elems[i] = new_val  // Works, because elems[i] deferences 
                        // the pointer to the actual value in elems
}
```

Read: [Gotchas](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Range#gotchas)

Also, if you're not modifying all fields, rather than using `Save` you can use `Update` as well. Refer: [GORM CRUD's Interface UPDATE](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html)

Comment: I change to `artists[key].IsSend = 1` but not working

Comment: after save i get this error `reflect: call of reflect.Value.Interface on zero Value
`

Comment: Show the struct once? And schema?

Comment: struct added to question

Comment: Do `DB.Debug().Save(&artists[i])` and share outptut

Comment: thanks, i used `DB.Save(&artists)` And by changing to  `DB.Save(&artists[i])` My problem was solved